# DATABASE SQLSTATE SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: database, configuration

Today we tried to check our website but we found this error. I don't know what happened exactly.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService() (line 79 of /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php).

Please I need help to fix this error as soon as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Try changing the DB host in settings.php to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory for background